# Baseline Duration vs. Duration vs. Actual Duration vs. Schedule Duration

Tags: microsoft-project, project-management

I am still not fully certain on the definitions of these terms, not as they relate to project but what they really mean.

Please can someone explain?

Comment: In what context did you hear these terms?

Comment: @timotree Initially I didn't hear it in any context, but the question I'm looking at now is asking why the duration of a certain work package task is higher than the baseline duration. I'd like to know what differentiates these terms.

Comment: From Microsoft Support [Baseline Duration](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Baseline-Duration-task-field-050ebbd5-dc99-42a5-b8a5-97d8098231bc). [Scheduled Duration](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Scheduled-Duration-task-field-37E6B673-FB24-4D8D-A742-90B8C102293E), [Actual Duration](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/actual-duration-task-field-d781ba93-30d3-4a28-aecc-9fa330fa7984)

Answer (score 0):

**Duration:** The number of 'working' time periods between the start date and the Finish date of the task. By default this is expressed in days (but it could be in minutes, hours, weeks, months, quarters or years.)

**Baseline Duration:** A point in time copy of the value of the duration field. When you save a baseline Project copies the value of a bunch of different fields (start, finish, duration, work, cost, etc) into a 'Baseline.' These are generally saved just prior to the project start but could be saved again if a major rework of the scope happens.

**Actual Duration:** The number of working time periods between the Actual Start date (the date on which the task 'actually' started and (in the case of a completed task) the Actual Finish (the date the task 'actually' finished) OR (in the case of a started but not yet finished task) the 'complete through date, which is the point at which the % complete of the task has reached in time.

**Scheduled Duration:** Basically, Scheduled Duration is a sort of estimate of the duration for a Manually Scheduled task if the manually scheduled task doesnt have an entered duration. For a Auto Scheduled task this will be the same as Duration. I dont have a lot of use for this field because I would never have a manually scheduled task in one of my projects. :-)